# How to convert .aspx page to pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I need to create a pdf from .aspx page. In .aspx page user will enter so many values in textbox and gridview. It also has some tabs with different sections. I did used iTextSharp for creating simple pdf. But here i need to get the values from the page and need to read the tab controls. So is it posible to use iTextSharp or is there any opensource dll available for converting .aspx to pdf..

Give me some idea?

Thanks..

Comment: useful link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504415/how-to-convert-aspx-to-pdf-using-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using ITextsharp library,this can be done by using HTMLWorker :

First Create String builder;

```
 private StringBuilder sb;
```

Then add pdf heading from textbox value as:

```
sb.Append("<p style=\"text-align: center;font-size:" + fontSize + "px;font-weight:" + (bold ? "bold" : "normal") + ";\">" + txtHeading + "</p>");
```

Then add subject to pdf from textbox value as:

```
sb.Append("<table><tr valign=\"top\"><td>Subj:</td><td style=\"font-size:" + fontSize + "px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;\">" + txtSubject.text + "</td></tr></table><br />");
```

Then add paragraphs from textbox value as:

```
sb.Append("<p style=\"text-align: left;font-size:" + fontSize + "px;font-weight:" + (bold ? "bold" : "normal") + ";\">" + txtParagraph + "</p><br/>");
```

for table creation take values in string[] array

```
sb.Append("<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" border=\"0.5\"><thead><tr align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">");
            foreach (string str in StringArray)
            {
                sb.Append("<th><strong>" + str + "</strong></th>");
            }
            sb.Append("</tr></thead>");
```

And so on.You can create pdf from textbox values of aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Itext Sharp quite easy .about tabs ,I dont know may be it will work ,as it works for paging ,I mean it converts all the matter in the paging ,in a single pdf
[Click Here For Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18040/Tutorials-on-creating-PDF-files-using-C-2-0)